# How to inject service has a constructor inside other class with typedi and type-graphql

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, typegraphql

here is my code. I try to inject services inside the resolver class but `ResourceService` has a constructor and it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

//ResourceService.ts

```
@Service()
export class ResourceService<T> {
  constructor(protected resources: ModelType<T>) {}

  async getById(_id: ObjectId): Promise<T | null> {
    return this.resources.findById(_id);
  }
}
```

//UserService.ts

```
@Service()
export class UserService extends  ResourceService<User>{
  async getUserByRole() {}
}
```

//Resolver.ts

```
@Resolver(() => User) 
export class UserResolver {
  @Inject()
  private userService: UserService;

  @Query()
  protected async getUser() {
    // this.userService.getById();
    // this.userService.getUserByRole();
  }
}
```